# Is it possible to use different time steps for bodies existing in the same world in Box2D?

Tags: box2d

I'm currently trying to play with timesteps to achieve a sort of "bullet-time"/"slow motion" effect in my game, and it works pretty much as expected: I decrease the time step (e.g. - from 1/60 to 1/300) and the simulation will slow down.

However, I think I want to introduce a game mechanic where, upon triggering "bullet-time"/"slo-mo," the main character controlled by the player doesn't slow down but everything else around him does.

So if there's a way to scale the timestep up/down for specific bodies in the physics simulation, that would be great.

If not, how would you suggest I try applying this game mechanic with Box2D? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of time step is not regarded as good practice as it can create tunneling of bodies. What you can do to have slow motion is make a global variable and multiply it with the velocities of the bodies. Now according to your need you can change the value of that variable.